# Virus disabled system restore and antivirus

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

Hi,
I have clicked on this link in Yahoo messenger:
`http://s56.megapicturehost.com/usercache/89413405/NewPhoto11.JPEG.zip`

it has disabled my antivirus and system restore and it reduces the speed of my internet and so on. Does anybody know what can I do in order to get rid of that virus?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Boot to safe mode with networking, update your virus definitions and run virus scans. If you can't clear it out that way, use a tool like [BartPE](http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/) and scan from the boot CD. It helps if you can at least get an ID for the virus. When you know what you are fighting you can find more specific steps on how to clean it.